# What word describes a word which by definition encompasses another?

Tags: single-word-requests

Hopefully the title conveyed my request with clarity.

An example:

*

> Egalitarianism encompasses feminism.

*

What word describes that relationship?
Where the former contains the latter and more (in context to the question).

Comment: I would use superset.

Comment: Show how you would use the word in a sentence. (The relationship is inclusion or comprehension.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is "hypernym"."
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponymy_and_hypernymy

Answer (score 0):

You could say that, if one object encompasses a subobject as well as other subobjects, it is a *superset* of that subobject.

Superset via [YourDictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/superset)

> With respect to another set, a set such that each of the elements of
> the other set is also an element of the set. : "The set of human beings
> is a superset of the set of children." "The set of characters "LBPG" is
> a superset of the set of characters "PG"."

In this case, Egalitarianism would be a *superset* of feminism, and feminism would be a *subset*.